# adding a command to another plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a project, where we have two plugins. I have a command which i definied in the "side - plugin". I want to add it to a menu of the main plugin at runtime. The main plugin should not know about the side plugin. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.eclipse.ui.menus` to contribute commands to the main menu or main toolbar.  In your side plugin, after you define the command add another extension:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution locationURI="menu:file?after=additions">
     <command commandId="z.ex.cmd.commands.sampleCommand"
           id="z.ex.cmd.menus.sampleCommand"/>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

This will contribute a command to the *File* menu.  All you need to know is the ID of the menu you want to contribute to (as defined in your main plugin), and an insertion point (or additions if it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Contributions take only command ids. So when contributing menu/toolbar items, you can use the ids of the commands that are defined in other plugins. For this, you neither have to know about the other plugin nor set dependency on that plugin.

Comment: Hmmm... what happends with the Conrtributions, when their id is not found? Because my "side-plugin" will not always be used...

Comment: If the command can't be found, then the contributed item wont appear in the menu/toolbar

Comment: Talked to my boss, he said altering the main plug is not an option. Is the MenuService of use to me?